# How do I free memory allocated to a void* member of a struct in my c project without breaking my GoogleTest project?

Tags: c++, malloc, googletest, free

I'm trying to free all the memory allocated in `testing_malloc()` with the method `testing_free()`. I am using a Google Test project to test my code and the MemoryLeakDetector mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70968385/23745070).
However, when I try to free the `private_data` I get the following heap corruption error.

> HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#835) at 0x00000263D9A97F40.
> CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

testing.h:

```
#ifndef testing_h
#define testing_h

typedef struct TestStruct {
    void* private_data;
} TestStruct;

void test_method();

int testing_malloc(int input, int is_negative, int length, TestStruct* out);
int testing_free(TestStruct* to_free);
#endif
```

testing.c:

```
#include "testing.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <memory.h>

struct TestStruct {
    void* private_data;
};

typedef struct InternalTestStruct {
    int* value_array;
    int* length;
    int* is_negative;
} InternalTestStruct;

int testing_malloc(int input, int is_negative, int length, TestStruct* out)
{
    InternalTestStruct* internaltesting;
    if (input < 0 || input > 9)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    internaltesting = (InternalTestStruct*)malloc(sizeof(TestStruct));
    if (!internaltesting)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    internaltesting->is_negative = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (!internaltesting->is_negative)
    {
        free(internaltesting);
        return 2;
    }
    *internaltesting->is_negative = is_negative;
    internaltesting->length = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (!internaltesting->length)
    {
        free(internaltesting->is_negative);
        free(internaltesting);
        return 2;
    }
    *internaltesting->length = length;
    internaltesting->value_array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * length);
    if (!(internaltesting->value_array))
    {
        free(internaltesting->length);
        free(internaltesting->is_negative);
        free(internaltesting);
        return 2;
    }
    memset(internaltesting->value_array, 0, sizeof(int) * length);
    internaltesting->value_array[0] = input;
    out->private_data = internaltesting;
    return 0;
}

int testing_free(TestStruct* to_free)
{
    InternalTestStruct* internaltesting = (InternalTestStruct*)to_free->private_data;
    free(internaltesting->value_array);
    free(internaltesting->length);
    free(internaltesting->is_negative);
    /*free(internaltesting);*/
    /*free(to_free->private_data);*/
    return 0;
}
```

test.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "../Testing/testing.h"
#include "../Testing/testing.c"


namespace testns
{

    TEST(construct_tests, construct_zero_does_not_leak) {
        MemoryLeakDetector leakDetector;
        int length = 1;
        int is_negative = 0;
        int expected_value = 0;
        TestStruct* zero = (TestStruct*)malloc(sizeof(void*));
        if (!zero)
        {
            FAIL();
        }
        int result = testing_malloc(expected_value, is_negative, length, zero);
        if (!zero->private_data || result != 0)
        {
            free(zero);
            FAIL();
        }
        testing_free(zero);
        free(zero);
    }
}
```

pch.h

```
//
// pch.h
//

#pragma once

#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <crtdbg.h>

class MemoryLeakDetector {
public:
    MemoryLeakDetector() {
        _CrtMemCheckpoint(&memState_);
    }

    ~MemoryLeakDetector() {
        _CrtMemState stateNow, stateDiff;
        _CrtMemCheckpoint(&stateNow);
        int diffResult = _CrtMemDifference(&stateDiff, &memState_, &stateNow);
        if (diffResult)
            reportFailure(stateDiff.lSizes[1]);
    }
private:
    void reportFailure(unsigned int unfreedBytes) {
        FAIL() << "Memory leak of " << unfreedBytes << " byte(s) detected.";
    }
    _CrtMemState memState_;
};
```

I tried both of the commented statements in `testing_free` but either one gives me the heap corruption message. If I leave them commented, the MemoryLeakDetector correctly reports that I'm leaking memory. I removed the MemoryLeakDetector and uncommented either of the commented statements in `testing_free` and still got the error.

I did note that I did not receive the exception using a console app to test testing_malloc and testing_free

console.c

```
#include "testing.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main(int charc, char** charv)
{
    int length = 1;
    int is_negative = 0;
    int expected_value = 0;
    int result;
    TestStruct* zero = (TestStruct*)malloc(sizeof(void*));
    if (!zero)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    result = testing_malloc(expected_value, is_negative, length, zero);
    if (!zero->private_data || result != 0)
    {
        free(zero);
        return 1;
    }
    testing_free(zero);
    free(zero);
    return 0;
}
```

So that leads me to believe that it is an issue with using Google Test.
How do I properly free the memory allocated by the following statement without breaking my GoogleTest project?

`internaltesting = (InternalTestStruct*)malloc(sizeof(TestStruct));`

Comment: First off: ` TestStruct* zero = (TestStruct*)malloc(sizeof(void*));` is wrong. Should be `TestStruct* zero = (TestStruct*)malloc(sizeof(TestStruct));` Alternatively, you could make it `TestStruct zero` and use &zero later as the parameter to the function call as the lifetime is ok in this situation.

Comment: Next, in testing_malloc `internaltesting = (InternalTestStruct*)malloc(sizeof(TestStruct));` has the same sort of error. It needs to be `internaltesting = (InternalTestStruct*)malloc(sizeof(InternalTestStruct));` . You need to allocate the amount of memory for the thing you are allocating.

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell, the is_negative and length members of InternalTestStruct should be plain old ints and not pointers to dynamically allocated ints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call `free`. The problem isn't how you call `free`, it's how you called `malloc`.

On one type of computer `TestStruct` is 8 bytes and `InternalTestStruct` is 24 bytes, so:

```
internaltesting = (InternalTestStruct*)malloc(sizeof(TestStruct));
```

this line allocates 8 bytes, but then you set all 24 bytes as if you had enough space for an `InternalTestStruct` which you don't. The extra 16 bytes aren't yours. Because you're using some kind of debug mode in your compiler (possibly by default), `free` checks the bytes before and after what you allocated to make sure you didn't touch them, to help catch bugs. You did touch them, so it caught the bug.

Solution: allocate the right number of bytes (`sizeof(InternalTestStruct)`)