# C++ default argument masks memory leak detection via _CrtMemDifference

Tags: c++, unit-testing, memory-leaks

Long-time reader, first-time asker.

I'm writing unit tests using the Microsoft unit test framework in Visual Studio 2013. I'm using a variation of the memory leak detection code described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2981185/4446293, which works very well. However, I want to name each instance of CrtCheckMemory in order to clearly identify the test case that produced the leak, and also provide a default test name. Here is the complete source code of my test case:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

#include <string>
#include <ostream>

#include <crtdbg.h>

// A default test name, allocated statically so as to definitely not affect the heap.
static const char* UNNAMED_TEST = "Unnamed Test";

// Instances of this struct should detect heap differences that occur
// while they are in scope.
struct CrtCheckMemory {
    _CrtMemState state1, state2, state3; 
    const char* tname;

    // Allowing this default argument to be used seems to
    // mask this class's ability to see heap changes.
    CrtCheckMemory(const char* testName = UNNAMED_TEST) : tname(testName) {
        _CrtMemCheckpoint(&state1);
    }

    ~CrtCheckMemory() {
        _CrtMemCheckpoint(&state2);
        if (_CrtMemDifference(&state3, &state1, &state2)) {
            std::ostringstream oss; oss << "MEMORY LEAK DETECTED in " << tname << "- see Debug output for details";
            Logger::WriteMessage(oss.str().c_str());
            _CrtMemDumpStatistics(&state3);
        }
    }
};

namespace TestLeakyCauldron
{
    TEST_CLASS(UnitTest1)
    {
    public:

        TEST_METHOD(DetectsALeak_Test) {
            CrtCheckMemory checker("DetectsALeak");
            malloc(1);
            Logger::WriteMessage("You should see a MEMORY LEAK DETECTED message for test DetectsALeak");
        }

        TEST_METHOD(LeaksButNoMessage_Test) {
            CrtCheckMemory checker();
            malloc(1);
            Logger::WriteMessage("You SHOULD see a MEMORY LEAK DETECTED message for test Unnamed Test, but you won't");
        }
    };
}
```

This works great as long as I actually supply a name to the CrtCheckMemory constructor. However, if I do not supply a name, leaks that occur while the CrtCheckMemory object is in scope are *not* detected (or at any rate, a "MEMORY LEAK DETECTED" message is not emitted to the "Tests" pane of the VS2013 Output window).

My question is, why does leak detection work in one case, but not the other?

I cannot see why supplying a default argument that is merely a statically-allocated pointer value would change the state of the CRT heap. I would guess that it has something to do with the internals of the _CrtMemCheckpoint() and _CrtMemDifference() implementations. But am I missing something important about how default arguments to ctors work? I don't see any opportunity for heap activity in the two different ctor cases (default argument vs explicit argument).

Note: I was originally using a std::string member to hold the test name in the CrtCheckMemory class, but I changed to use const string* and string literals to avoid the possibility of the std::string constructor and destructor changing the heap state in ways that were visible to _CrtMemCheckpoint().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, which is basically that I spend more time working in Java than C++ these days.

```
CrtCheckMemory crtcm();
```

is not the correct way to declare an instance using the default ctor. That would be:

```
CrtCheckMemory crtcm;
```

As Hans Passant points out, this is C++'s "most vexing parse": Visual C++ accepts the "incorrect" declaration because it is a correct decl for a function accepting no parameters and returning a CrtCheckMemory. It does issue a warning (C4930) which I had previously overlooked. No leak is reported when the erroneous decl is used, because no instance of CrtCheckMemory is actually created in the test scope. Correcting this problem leads to the expected leak detection message.

Comment: It is not an incorrect declaration.  Google "c++ most vexing parse" to learn more.  And consider using /WX so you'll only get bitten once.

Comment: Ah, right. So the compiler sees a declaration of a function named crtcm accepting no arguments and returning a CrtCheckMemory. Thanks for the pointer to the /WX option.